# Saving Browsing Sessions in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, session, tabbed-browsing

This isn't a <del>programming</del> code question, more of a browser UX issue. I know that in Firefox and Opera (perhaps Safari?), you can save your current browsing session to open later when you quit the app (I'm talking in Mac terms right now).

As far as I can tell, it's not very easy to do this in Chrome. I've got like 30 tabs open, and I need to restart my computer…I'd hate to lose all of that browsing data (bookmarking all of those pages loses the history of that session…plus it's a pain in the ass). It would also be nice if I could save multiple sessions that could be loaded asynchronously of each other similar to Opera.

Is there some sort of workaround for saving browsing sessions in Chrome?

Comment: "This isn't a programming question" <-- Why have you posted it here then?

Comment: dude…it's a legit question for programming as I need to test in Chrome, and commonly have programming resources open in multiple tabs…it's just not a code question…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why yes, you can enable that in the preferences:

[image: Enabling Last Session]

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstood the question, just go to the preferences (chrome://settings/browser) and select "Reopen the pages that were open last" option